# How can I create a method which create a range of objects generically?

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

Whenever I program C#, I consitently use Linq both because I like it and it allows me to think like a functional programmer, which I often find a lot easier than imperative programming. A convention I often use when creating random lists of objects is the following:

```
var animals= Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(n => new Animal()).ToList();
```

I know this is (likely slower) syntatic sugar for a for loop that adds items onto a list. And that's perfectly acceptable to me, because it doesn't offend my sensibilites. Here's what I don't like:

var animals= **Enumerable.Range**(0, 100).**Select**(n => new Animal()).**ToList()**;

I would like to make a helper Func that Does this with even less typing. Ideally, I'd like to type:

```
var animals = NewRange(0, 100, Animal);
```

But I'm getting hung up on how to do this (if it's even possible). I could use reflection and all kinds of other gross stuff (yuck!), but without that, I can't figure it out. Here's the closest I've gotten:

```
public Func<int, Type, List<object>> NewRange = (n, t) => Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(o => new t()).ToList();
```

But that won't compile (for obvious reasons). Anybody got some advice on how I could create my handy-dandy function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you ultimately just want an IEnumerable, initialized with n instances all using a default constructor?

What about something like this:

```
public static List<T> CreateList<T>(int numberOfItems) where T : new()
{       
    var result = new List<T>(numberOfItems);
    for (int ix = 0; ix < numberOfItems; ix++)
    {
        result.Add(new T());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Actually he wanted a `List<>`.

Comment: Good catch. Updated to return a list instead.

Comment: Your style is very different from mine :). I would suggest setting the `List` capacity since you know it to begin with.

Comment: Change your method to be the name OP wants and I think this is the best answer.

Comment: Updated for those comments. The default capacity is nice, but tends to be a micro-optimization for every scenario I've ever seen. It's only noticeable for very large objects and/or insanely high array sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You need a type constraint to ensure you can instantiate `T`, so:

```
List<T> NewRange<T>(int howMany) where T : new()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, howMany).Select(n => new T()).ToList();
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
var animals = NewRange<Animal>(100);
```

Comment: Good, fast answer. I'm not a fan of using Enumerable.Range though since you really don't need a range of incrementing numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just try something like this:

```
public static List<T> NewRange<T>(int n) where T: new()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(_ => new T()).ToList();
}
```

Or with expression-bodied member:

```
public static List<T> NewRange<T>(int n) where T : new() => 
        Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(_ => new T()).ToList();
```

And use it:

```
var animals = NewRange<Animal>(100);
```

Comment: Beat me by 7 seconds! ;-)

Comment: I was surprise that you posted answer after 7 seconds and then @Tim posted after 5 seconds :)

Comment: Good answer that will work, but similar to below I'm not sure why the Range method is useful (other than the fact that it's used in the question). It's designed for incrementing lists, which seems like a strange fit for this use case.

Comment: Your first answer won't even compile. You're missing a semicolon and the type after the function `NewRange<t>`. See the other answers for the correct syntax. Also your call example should pass a number, not `n`. That's probably the reason for the downvotes, in case you wonder. I don't downvote, I prefer to comment so everybody benefits.

Comment: @RacilHilan Thanks, I really missed semicolon and type)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a lambda to your function to create the new object:

```
public static List<T> NewRange<T>(int n, Func<T> NewObject) {
    return Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(_ => NewObject()).ToList();
}
```

Then call it like:

```
var Animals = NewRange(10, () => new Animal());
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you can manage your question without any Reflections

Here is a small example how you could simplyfy it with a generic type:

```
public void Main()
{
   var animals = NewRange<Animal>(0, 100);
}

public static List<T> NewRange<T>(int n, int b)
{
   return (List<T>)Enumerable.Range(n, b).Select(instance => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T))).ToList();
}
```

I hope this will answer your question correctly and will fit your need

Comment: Parameters n and b have no use in your function. Also the new constraint like others suggested is a much cleaner approach.